# Custom push notification sound not playing

Tags: apple-push-notifications, javaapns

I'm using the following payload to send push notification:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"You got a notification!","sound":"mysound.caf"}}
```

I have the 'mysound.caf' in www/res/sound/mysound.caf and have added it to the 'Copy bundle resources' section of my app. When I send the notification, it's not played. I keep reading things saying to make sure the sound exists in the 'application bundle' but there's no clear way I can see to do this other than adding it the way I've already done.

I'm registering with:

```
{"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"}
```

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Note; I'm also using phonegap which plays the sound correctly once I click through to the app.